# Calling GPG4win from Moveit central command line app

Tags: encryption

I received an error while decrypting a file encrypted by one of my vendor using moveit central(Ipswitch product ver8.0).

However it fails, alternately it works using gpg4win due to some legacy systems at vendor end. 
Now I am trying to call the gpg4win using central's command line app process.

The command line app path- is the CWD where the application is installed on the server. 
However I am confused with command line paramters.

What I manged is 
Command line ap path: C:\PROGRA~1\DeCompress\

Command line app_appparms: >> [InputFile] [OutputFile] **ascii crlf de3** the latter half of this parameter ascii and crlf de3 this I have picked up from another job I have. Not sure what parameters need to come herewith GPG4win.

Kindly consider this on priority.

Thanks